# Excel Conditional Formatting Changing formatting rules

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I have an excel sheet where conditional formatting is extensively used to create a Gantt chart.  Is there any way to change the cell color specified in the rules (about 15 rules) without amending each and every rule?

Comment: no.  Assuming a rule cover a range of say A1 to A15, you do not need to change it in the 15 cells, you just need to change the rule that applies to the range.  If you have multiple rules that apply to the range, then you need to change the each rule for the range.

Comment: Thanks but what the rules are doing is changing the border depending on whether the cell is at the start, middle or end of the gantt chart bar.  The color is say green.  If I want all conditionally formatted green cells to turn blue, is there anyway to do this without changing all the rules?  Or do I have to write VB code?

Comment: Thanks pnuts.  I think you are right.